# Which is faster, for loop or LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, loops, collections

I have two lists of double values same as here:

```
 List<double> list1 = something;
 List<double> list2 = somethingElse;
```

I want to subtract these two lists. Lists are huge and I want to do it as fast as possible. Which of the below methods is faster:

```
public double CalculateDistance(List<double> list1, List<double> list2)
{
    double dist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != list1.Count; i++)
    {
        dist += Math.Pow(list1 [i] - list2 [i], 2.0);
    }
    return dist;
}
```

or this:

```
public double CalculateDistance(List<double> list1, List<double> list2)
{
    double dist = list1.Zip(list2, (v1, v2) => Math.Pow(v1 - v2, 2.0)).Sum();
    return dist;
}
```

I dont know what LINQ does under the hood so I'm not sure which one is better.

Comment: Measure it yourself... But first, profile and determine that this method is *really* on the hot path in your application.

Comment: You should do some error checking to ensure that both lists contain the same amount of records, and if not be willing to handle that or throw an exception.

Comment: yes they have the same amount or records. Im sure for that. I just want to understand which leads to a better performance

Comment: ...and I dont need to throw any exceptions as it is quit expensice when good performance is in question.

Comment: LINQ doesn't do any 'magic' under the hood - if anything it introduces more overhead as it is just iterating as usual in the background. The benefits of LINQ are more in the simplicity and readability of code.

Comment: What is your criteria for good performance? How many times does this operation run in a second? How many records? Have you profiled it? What were the results?

Comment: I dont know why people in here, always try to be complicated (honestly). Of course that I want to process these two lists within less amount of time (seconds).

Comment: Write the code both ways. Run it both ways. Now you know which is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. Using a loop has less overhead than LINQ, so that is a good start.

Use the `<` operator in the loop condition, that is the standard way of writing such a loop, so it's more likely that the compiler will recognise it and optimise it properly.

Using `Math.Pow` to square a number is not effective. It's somewhere in the ballpark of 100 times faster to multiply it by itself:

```
public double CalculateDistance(List<double> list1, List<double> list2) {
  double dist = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
    double n = list1[i] - list2[i];
    dist += n * n;
  }
  return dist;
}
```

#### Edit:

Using PLINQ you would get a better performance for large sets. Testing it on my computer I found that with less than 10000 items it's not faster to use PLINQ. For lists with 10 million items, I got about 40% shorter execution time.

I also found that using a projection I got about 30% shorter execution time than using `Zip`:

```
public double CalculateDistance(List<double> list1, List<double> list2) {
  return
    ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, list1.Count).Select(i => {
      double n = list1[i] - list2[i];
      return n * n;
    }).Sum();
}
```

Comment: For really long collections (e.g. 10+ million elements each), using PLINQ with zipping and sum would probably be even faster than regular imperative loop... :)

Comment: Yes lists may have millions of data, but not 10+.

Comment: @xXx Processing two lists of 5 million items each yields ~50 ms for imperative solution, ~144 ms for LINQ and ~20 ms for PLINQ (all in LINQPad). What performance is 'good enough' then? Perceived performance is the same...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Thank You for answering. In this case Im going to use PLINQ.

Comment: @xXx You should measure for yourself first. If you happen to have a smaller data set, the overhead of PLINQ might make it slower. It all *depends*...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek yes yes definitely I will measure it for my case. Anyway I learned something new from you and it was worth to post the question in here.

Comment: @xXx: Use a projection instead of `Zip` if you are using PLINQ. I added some results and an example above.